# How many possible assignments does a a CNF sentence have?

Tags: logic, artificial-intelligence

I'm having some trouble understanding the following:

When we look at satisfiability problems in conjunctive normal form, an underconstrained problem is one with relatively few clauses constraining the variables. For eg. here is a randomly generated 3-CNF sentence with five symbols and five clauses.
(Each clause contains 3 randomly selected distinct symbols, each of which is negated with 50% probability.)

```
 (¬D ∨ ¬B ∨ C) ∧ (B ∨ ¬A ∨ ¬C) ∧ (¬C ∨ ¬B ∨ E) ∧ (E ∨ ¬D ∨ B) ∧ (B ∨ E ∨ ¬C)
```

16 of the 32 possible assignments are models of this sentence, so, on an average, it would take just 2 random guesses to find the model.

---

I don't understand the last line- saying that there are 32 possible assignments. How is it 32? And how are only 16 of them models of the sentence? Sorry, but i'm finding this concept a bit confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2^5=32 possible assignments of the two values *true* and *false* to 5 variables:

```
1:  00000
2:  00001
3:  00010
    ...
31: 11110
32: 11111
```

16 of those assignments satisfy (I didn't check) the given formula, thus are models of it.

Comment: Thanks- but why does it say that it would take just 2 random guesses to find the model? Is it something like saying if the selected 16 assignments are unsatifiable, then the other 16 will be satisfiable?

Comment: Each assignment is either satisfying or unsatisfying. So if you pick an assignment by random (by flipping 5 coins), then the generated assignment will be a satisfying one in 50% of the cases.

Comment: @Ghost Keep in mind, that these 50% are a property of the particular formula you presented. It's not true in general.